# Selecting non null values from columns of different types in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a property values table as below and I know that only one of the *_value fields will contain a value, the others will be NULL.

What is the most efficient way to select the value of the column only that is not null?

I have tried

```
SELECT property_id, COALESCE(int_value, str_value, etc)
```

but this doesn't work because they are different column types, similarly with NULLIF. I can cast all the values but I don't want to lose the value types.

```
property_values
-----------------------------------------------
property_id      | integer
int_value        | integer
str_value        | character varying
time_value       | timestamp without time zone
txt_value        | text
dec_value        | numeric
bool_value       | boolean
json_value       | jsonb
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You cannot do what you want, at least "reasonably".  As you note, `coalesce()` doesn't work because of the type conflict.  That gets close to the root of the problem:  a column in a result set has to have a specific type.

So, what type do you want the result to be?  You could decide on a "universal" type, such as a string.  I'm not sure that is such a good idea for your use case.